# How to implement different transitions in and out of three different states

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to make a button that has different background colors (lightgreen, green, darkgreen) based on three states (default, hover, active), and transitions between the states in this way:

When the user:

- hovers over the button (default -> hover), it should instantly transition from lightgreen to green.
- clicks on the button (hover -> active), it should instantly transition from green to darkgreen.
- releases the click (active -> hover), it should fade from darkgreen to green.
- 'unhovers', (hover -> default), it should fade from green to lightgreen.

The only way I've been able to do it is with JavaScript, which is not ideal. From what I understand, this may not be possible because I can only define one transition for hover, which happens for both default -> hover and clicked -> hover. What I want would require being able to have the transition from default -> hover be 0s/none, and the transition from clicked -> hover be 1s/something. Is this possible without using JavaScript?

Here are two snippets of what I've tried so far. The first one exhibits the desired behavior when clicked, while the second one does so when hovered.

```css
button {
  height: 100px; width: 400px;
  border: none; outline: none;

  background-color: lightgreen;
  transition: 1s;
}
/* unwanted fade going from default -> hover */
button:hover {
  background-color: green;
  transition: 1s;
}

button:active {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  transition: 0s;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

```css
button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  
  background-color: lightgreen;
  transition: 1s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: green;
  transition: 0s;
}
/* wanted but missing fade when going from active -> hover */
button:active {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  transition: 0s;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Comment: Agreed, I don't think this is possible without JS.

Comment: Was just about to post that I dont think its possible without using JS. There is not a good way to detect the button on/off states with CSS combined with what is currently being asked

Comment: And yet [this](http://www.keithclark.co.uk/labs/css-fps/nojs/) is possible without JS :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a crazy idea. Alternate between background-color and background-image. This works in Chrome & Safari. Firefox has not implemented background image transitions.

```css
button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  
  background-color: lightgreen;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: green;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAAHCAIAAABRDCAKAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB98MEhYaBya+xvUAAAAdaVRYdENvbW1lbnQAAAAAAENyZWF0ZWQgd2l0aCBHSU1QZC5lBwAAABNJREFUCNdjZGhgwA+YGBiGjQoAfXAAjqFknA0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
  transition: background-image 1s;
}
button:active {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABEAAAAOCAIAAABGj2DjAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB98MEhYUHtxWQ7sAAAAdaVRYdENvbW1lbnQAAAAAAENyZWF0ZWQgd2l0aCBHSU1QZC5lBwAAABhJREFUKM9jZEhhIBUwMTCM6hnVM6j1AABGTwCARo/YOwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
  transition: 0s;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Comment: Nice! Could the inline image be just a single pixel?

Comment: Yeah but I generally avoid that because some browsers have performance issues tiling a 1 pixel background.

Comment: Also, what's your procedure for dealing with data URIs for images? I'm using a web service to convert them right now, but that doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but I don't really use them for images. They're useful for places like this website so I can easily inline an image.